# Вызов метода класса через указатель на объект

Tags: c++, функции, классы, полиморфизм, виртуальная-функция

```
class Base
{
    public:
    void method(){}
};

class Child : public Base
{
    public:
    void method()
    {
        std::cout << "child" << std::endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
   Base *base = new Child();
   
   base->method();
   return 0;
}
```

base->method() в данном случае ничего не выводит. Можете объяснить почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class Base
{
    public:
    virtual void method(){}
};
```

Обратите внимание на ключевое слово `virtual`. Только виртуальные функции вызываются с использованием механизма динамического полиморфизма.

Не виртуальные функции-члены связываются во время компиляции статически, на основании указанного типа.

Comment: спасибо, вспомнил